# Insert API called image in mail using thymeleaf, springboot

Tags: spring-boot, image, api, email

I have an app where it displays few image on a webpage. These images are loaded through backend (java - springboot) api which returns image from the file path which is then converted to blob and displayed on frontend. So there is no direct access to image using any URL, it can be accessed through API only with some authentication.

Now problem is I need to embed this image in the mail when user shares it.
But I'm not able to find any way for that.

In the backend, I have tried converting image to base64 and blob like this,

```java
image = servePicture(details.getCoverImage());
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(image);
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
result = encoder.encodeToString(details.getCoverImage().getBytes());
String base64string = result;
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64string);
Blob bitmap = new SerialBlob(decodedByte);
```

Then using this blob value in email template,

I have tried adding in my email template

```html
<img width="45px" height="45px" alt="coverImage" th:src="@{bitmap}"></img>
//api call
<img width="45px" height="45px" alt="coverImage" th:src="@{http://localhost:3000/api/files/shareimg/TY_FLR_120.png}" ></img>
//direct file path
<img width="45px" height="45px" alt="coverImage" th:src="@{D:/shareData/Flowers/TY_FLR_120.png}" ></img>
```

But this does not work. Also there is another issue with gmail blocking blob images

Is there any other way which can help to show inline images which are loading thru API?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decode base64 back to Blob, just display the image in base64 string.

Try to replace your `th:src` to

```
th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+ base64string}"
```